# How does the increment operator behave in Java?

Tags: java

Why is the result 8 and not 9?

By my logic:

1. `++x` gives 4
2. 4 + 4 gives 8, so `x = 8`
3. But after that statement `x` should be increased due to `x++`, so it should be 9.

What's wrong with my logic?:

```
int x = 3;
x = x++ + ++x;
System.out.println(x); // Result: 8
```

Answer (score 21):

You should note that the expression is evaluated from the left to the right :

First `x++` increments x but returns the previous value of 3.

Then `++x` increments x and returns the new value of 5 (after two increments).

```
x = x++ + ++x;
    3   +  5     = 8
```

However, even if you changed the expression to

```
x = ++x + x++;
```

you would still get 8

```
x = ++x + x++
     4  +  4   = 8
```

This time, the second increment of x (`x++`) is overwritten once the result of the addition is assigned to x.

Comment: As this answer correctly states, the result strongly depends on the fact that expressions are being evaluated left-to-right, as Java guarantees. Some other languages (notably C and C++) lack this guarantee, making the same reasoning invalid in such contexts. (I know this is about Java, only, but wanted to stress this anyway)

Comment: Is it right?: "You should note that the expression is evaluated from the left to the right "                                                                                                 x = x++ + ++x;
      3     +    5     = 8                                                                                     Why 5 ? It must be 4, is not it?

Answer (score 1):

++x is called preincrement and x++ is called postincrement. x++ gives the previous value and ++x gives the new value.